# Unsupported attribute 27 in CoA-Request from IP:PORT

Tags: wifi, openwrt, radius

I have a freeradius server setup on my ubuntu VM. My Edgecore AP is connected to a MicroTik and Laptop. I have OpenWRT running on the AP and I'm able to connect a client using WPA2 Enterprise encryption. I'm trying to send a CoA request from the VM such as "Session-Timeout" however, observing the logs on the AP, I receive the message I've included in the title. Is CoA completely unsupported or hostapd simply can't understand the incoming request?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Authorization Extensions (RFC 5176) is default disabled in hostapd.

set `radius_das_port=3799` in your conf to enable this feature.

https://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/wpa/hostapd/hostapd.conf